# Display and hide property caching always in browser?

Tags: javascript, browser-cache

I have an option with `display:none`, and this seems to be cached in the browser. Is there a way to avoid this?

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="2">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="B" id="countrys" value="country" onclick="fun(this.value)"></td>
        <td><font size="2">Country</font></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="B" id="states" value="state" onclick="fun(this.value)"></td>
        <td><font size="2">State</font></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="B" id="citys" value="city" onclick="fun(this.value)"></td>
        <td><font size="2">City</font></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/senthil4040/tf2ug/)

Comment: There's no code here with `display:none`. Are you sure that's what you meant?

Comment: style.display='' and style.display='none'

Comment: It'll stay that way until you set the `display` property to something else.

Comment: is there any way to do this???

Comment: How come css prop getting cached..